# html not showing svg file in img tag

Tags: html, laravel, image, svg, laravel-blade

I am writing a mail class in Laravel that show a svg file from url inside an imp tag. When the email is sent the svg file is replaced with a blue question mark and is not showing the alt text. But when I view the blade as a web page it is working fine.

Here is the code for the svg file:

```html
<a href="{{ $url }}">
  <img alt="SVG" height="36" src='https://exmaple.com/someFile.svg' width="127">
</a>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It might be due to the fact that svgs are not supported by all email clients. Maybe helpful informations about that topic here: https://css-tricks.com/a-guide-on-svg-support-in-email/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many email clients don't support SVG. Unfortunately, email clients don't update like browsers.
You can follow this link for the guidelines about using SVG in mail.
http://stylecampaign.com/blog/2014/01/basics-of-svg-in-email/